# Transform and Reverse Animation of an object

Tags: ios, swift

I created a simple fish animation with the following code in viewDidLoad() [trimmed it down a bit]:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: xStart,y: yStart))

    //func addCurveToPoint(_ endPoint: CGPoint, controlPoint1 controlPoint1: CGPoint, controlPoint2 controlPoint2: CGPoint)
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: xEnd, y: 239), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 373), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 110))

    // create a new CAKeyframeAnimation that animates the objects position
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    // set the animations path to our bezier curve
    anim.path = path.CGPath

    anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    anim.duration = 5.0
    imageView.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "Go fishy!")
```

[image]

My challenge right now was trying to have the fishy swim back from the other side of the screen.

In essence, swim back in the same path, but rotating the fish to have it face from right to left (instead of left to right, or flip on y-axis).

What's the best approach to this problem? Should I have two fishes, one facing one way and one facing another? If so, how would I add a delay to space those two fishes out? I'm open to better solutions.

Comment: You could scale the fish to -1 on the `x` axis and run the animation the other way.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Since I'm a n00b with swift, I tried to use UIView.animatewithduration where on completion it would do a transform, but it failed. I'm now using this approach with 'anim', but I don't know how to trigger the completion point and transform with anim.